# Forbid user to call (privileged) functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, private-members

Is there a way to forbid the use of some methods in the browser console? Say I would like for the browser to be able to use these functions, but not the user.

I am trying to do a (money) counter. Here is my code:

```js
// Counter declaration
var myCnt;

// Counter constructor
function Counter(initVal) {

    // Private variables
    var cnt = initVal;
    var that = this;

    // Privileged functions
    this.add = function (val) {
        switch (val) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 5: cnt += val; break;
            default: alert("Wrong value!"); return;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    this.show = function () { // Updates the value
        document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML = cnt;
        return;
    }
}

/* // This self-invoking function gets the initial (last) value of the counter from an xml file.
(function loadLast() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(), container = document.getElementById("cnt");
    var theVal = 0;
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            theVal = parseInt(xml.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
            myCnt = new Counter(theVal);
            myCnt.show();
        }
    }
    xml.open("GET", "lastval.xml", true);
    xml.send();
})(); */

myCnt = new Counter(0); // Normally, this object is instantiated in the self-invoking function above
myCnt.show();
```

```css
div#cnt {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}
            
div#btn-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Money Box Counter</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="cnt"></div>
        <div id="btn-container">
            <button type="button" onclick="myCnt.add(1); myCnt.show();">+1</button>
            <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myCnt.add(2); myCnt.show();">+2</button>
            <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="myCnt.add(5); myCnt.show();">+5</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, for instance, is there a way to deny user access to the `Counter.add` method without making it private? So only the client, or the **user but only through the buttons**, could modify the counter.

I thought of using the `arguments.callee.caller` property within the `Counter.add` method, but I read this should not be used as of ES5.

Another question would be if this is a good practice? I mean, what I am trying to do is hide some functions that should not be used by users themselves...

Thank you! And have a good one!

Comment: no, either it is "private" or it is accessible to everyone. Simply put the code inside an [tag:iife]

Comment: You could simply add the click event listener using JavaScript. So within an IIFE, create the private function. Then set `button.onclick = function() { private(1); };` or whatever you like.

Comment: Just so you know, if the use knows their way around the dev tools they'll still be able to get into your code and step through and do whatever they like; they just won't be able to call directly from the console.